# How to avoid crashes on call back to deallocated delegate objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, crash, automatic-ref-counting

My application is on ARC and I still see few crashes. I then saw that I was setting my view controller as delegate of an alert view and then when the alert is on screen, on tap on "OK" button I was moving back to previous view and my current view controller was getting dealloc-ed. After it is getting dealloc-ed, I got a call from UIKit for the alert view and it crashes. As a safe handling, I created a property for `UIAlertView` and in the `dealloc` now, I am setting delegate of this `UIAlertView` to `nil`. This is working fine now.

I see another crash happening randomly:

```
-[CFString release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xd2de900
```

My question here is that there are lot many places where I create local instances of some objects (custom view controllers or iOS objects like `UIAlertView`) and set my view controller as delegate of it. Do I need to create class level properties for all of them and the delegate on them to `nil` in the `dealloc`? Is there any other easy alternative to make sure no call back happens after delegate object is gone.

Comment: Can you set the delegate to be a weak reference of the object in question? The __weak variable should set itself to nil when its referenced object is dealloc'ed.

Comment: I think the most obvious answer is don't deallocate objects that are still in use as a delegate.

Comment: @HotLicks That should be an answer. That should be *the* answer.

Comment: Things seemed pretty standard until you mentioned that your controller was dealloc'd and then you got a call from UIKit for your alert view.  What do you mean you got a call from UIKit?  It sounds as though you are retaining an instance of your UIAlertView and reusing it, which could be part of your problem.

Comment: I get these messages at 2 occassions 1) -[MyViewControllerController alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:] 2) [UIAlertViewAccessibility(SafeCategory) _performPopup:animationType:revealedBySpringBoardAlert:]